# MVC ViewModel Custom Property not populating if null exists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel

I have a very simple viewmodel, based on a Customer domain model.

I'm adding one property to it: **CustomerNameAddress** which is made up of the CustomerName, Contact and Town of the domain model.

However, if any of CustomerName, Contact or Town are **null** - then CustomerNameAddress is also null.

Is there anyway of checking for null within my query below, and changing it to "", so that my viewmodel works correctly?

I had tried:

```
CustomerNameAddress = (p.CustomerName || "") + ", " + (p.Contact || "") + ", " + (p.Town || "")
```

... but VS advised Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

My controller code is below.

Thank you,

Mark

```
    public JsonResult Lookup(string id)
    {
        string userName = null;

    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    var customers = from p in db.Customers
                    where p.UserName.Equals(userName)
                    select new CustomerLookupViewModel
                    {
                        CustomerId = p.CustomerId,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        CustomerNameAddress = p.CustomerName + ", " + p.Contact + ", " + p.Town
                    };

        return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I amended the code to:

[image: ss]

But now get the error on p.Contact (underlined above) advising: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

However, my viewmodel clearly has Contact as a string:

```
 public class CustomerLookupViewModel
{
    public string CustomerNameAddress { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Customer Contact")]
    public string Contact { get; set; }
```

**2nd Update - now working**

I updated the conditions to be enclosed in brackets, and it's now working:

```
CustomerNameAddress = ((p.CustomerName == null) ? "" : (p.CustomerName + ", ")) +
                        ((p.Contact == null) ? "" : (p.Contact + ", ")) +
                        ((p.Town == null) ? "" : (p.Town))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition operator [`? :`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
 CustomerNameAddress = (p.CustomerName == null || p.Contact == null || p.Town == null ) ? "" : p.CustomerName + ", " + p.Contact + ", " + p.Town
```

Query would be.

```
var customers = from p in db.Customers
                where p.UserName.Equals(userName)
                select new CustomerLookupViewModel
                {
                    CustomerId = p.CustomerId,
                    Email = p.Email,
                    CustomerNameAddress =  (p.CustomerName == null || p.Contact == null ||  p.Town == null ) ? "" : p.CustomerName + ", " + p.Contact + ", " + p.Town

                };
```

Comment: hi Adil - for that, I got the error: Error: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Comment: There was a typo, check it now.

Comment: Thanks again - using your and von v's example, I've updated my question, to show screenshots of the controller, and of my viewmodel - which is giving the error noted.  I can't see why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway of checking for null within my query below, and
>   changing it to "", so that my viewmodel works correctly?

something like this should do the trick

```
CustomerNameAddress = 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.CustomerName) ? "" : (p.CustomerName + ", ")) + 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Contact) ? "" : (p.Contact + ", ")) + 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Town) ? "" : (p.Town + ", "))
```

You might want to create a procedure for that so you can reuse that simple logic.

Comment: Hi - for that I got the error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' on: (p.Contact + ", ") + string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Town)

Comment: Ah you need to enclose each if-else shorthand in a parenthesis, sorry I missed that.